# How can I fix this javascript with some chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So if you are any sort of clg fan, you'll occasionally visit azubu.tv to watch them. If you go into the chat, using chrome, you can't change your text color. The reason is in  line 689 of the chat js. (it's best to pop it out since it's in an iframe). There is an extra = in the comparison that works in firefox but not chrome.

I did  not code this site. However, is there anyway to use a chrome plugin to permafix that function? I've already sent out a code update request to the admin -- a month ago. I've been just opening up the javascript console to do it manually but I'd like to help others.

Comment: Does the downvoter care for an explanation or a hint ? Just downvoting a new user without a word isn't all that helpful...

Comment: Probably a tsm fan. hue.

Answer (score 0):

I isn't expected people to develop extensions (or plugins) to fix web pages' .js, because it would take a lot of effort in reverse engineering and development, and the extension will become obsolete as soon the server administrator fixes his own js.

Extensions can do it, but are a very odd way to do that.

I don't know who voted you down without a comment; it's not the way we used to do it here.

Comment: Right! I agree with what you said but I've already reverse engineered it. When the chat is active I sit there teaching people how to do with with the javascript console. I can bet you good money the admins will not update the code for a good long time.

Comment: Ok, then I recommend writing an extension that changes the <script> content if js is in html file, or deleting <script src="..."> and replacing it with your script version.  If the bug is in a function, you can simply insert a script tag with your version of the function: using the same function name will replace the original.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment Yoargentino, but if you ever read the docs you'd know that wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi, what docs? What wouldn't work?  Please specify.  Sorry, I don't know your specific scenario, but my suggestion works in some cases.  And for more accuracy, you should try to change it before the original script runs (not always easy to do).  I know it is an open answer.